# calling child class function

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

How can I call a child function from a pointer of type parent that points to the child?

```
class a{
public:
    virtual void print(){cout << "From a" << endl;}
};

class b: public a{
public:
    void print(){cout << "Form b" << endl;}
    void printFunction(){cout << "Exist in b" << endl;}
};

int main() {

    a* Obj = new b;

    Obj->print();
    Obj->printFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I have a pointer of type "a" that points to "b".
I want to call "printFunction" that's defined only in class b.

I got this error:

> 'class a' has no member named 'printFunction'

The question is how can I call "printFunction" using this pointer?
or how To apply casting here?

Comment: You can't - you need to downcast

Comment: If you need `Obj` to use `b`'s interface, then `Obj` needs to be a `b*`.

Comment: @UnholySheep afaik that would be upcasting

Comment: Okay but if i have base class called shape and derived classes everyone inherits from it and has additional function and i made array[4] of type Shape and i want every index to be any of the derived classes how can i do that @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux use `dynamic_cast` to check if a given `shape*` is pointing at the desired derived class that you want to call into.

Comment: You need to have a (pure) virtual function in `a` and implement it in `b`. A piece of program that handles `a`s should never know that `b` or any other derived class ever exists. This is the whole purpose of having derived classes. I recommend getting a book on object oriented software design.

Answer (score 5):

Use `dynamic_cast`:

```
class a{
public:
    virtual ~a(){}
    virtual void print(){ cout << "From a" << endl; }
};

class b: public a{
public:
    void print(){ cout << "Form b" << endl; }
    void printFunction(){ cout << "Exist in b" << endl; }
};

int main() {

    a* Obj = new b;

    Obj->print();

    b* bObj = dynamic_cast<b*>(a);
    if (bObj)
        bObj->printFunction();

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: Or static cast. But only when you know the type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You could downcast using [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) conversion

```
class base {
  public:
    void print() {std::cout << "base class print";}
};

class derived : public base {
  public: 
    void printFunction() {std::cout << "derived class print";}
};

int main() {

  base* ptr_derrived  = new derived();

  if(Derived* d = dynamic_cast<derived*>(ptr_derived) {
    std::cout << "downcast successful\n";
    d->printFunction(); // safe to call
  }

  delete ptr_derrived;

}
```

Comment: Can you just tell me what is the different between these two lines `dynamic_cast<derrived*>(ptr_derrived)->printFunction();` and `((derrived*)ptr_derrived)->printFunction();`

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is almost exclusively used for handling polymorphism. Which is your intention. 

The `C-style cast ` can be used as a replacement for the `dynamic_cast` in some instances, but can be extremely dangerous because of the ability to devolve into a `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: The "new-style casts" in this case `dynamic_cast` were introduced to give programmers a chance to state their intentions more clearly and for the compiler to catch more errors.

Comment: A secondary reason for introducing the new-style cast was that C-style casts are very hard to spot in a program

Comment: You should test a `dynamic_cast` for failure by seeing if the ptf returned is `= nullptr`.

Comment: Dynamic cast is almost exclusively used to patch up a broken design. It is not a proper way to handle polymorphism. One should use a virtual function instead.

Comment: this kind sounds like a step toward need of observer or ECS patterns.